# Labeling in Prolog constraint programming

Tags: prolog, clpfd, instantiation-error

I am new to Prolog and currently working on a simple constraint programming problem. So I have four real numbers A,B,C,D with the property such that
A+B+C+d = A*B*C*D = 7.11
Since it is easier to work with integer, I tried the following implementation:

```
   :- use_module(library(clpfd)).
   grocery(Vars):-
      Vars=[A,B,C,D],
      X #= 100 * A,
      Y #= 100 * B,
      Z #= 100 * C,
      W #= 100 * D,
      X+Y+Z+W #= 711,
      X*Y*Z*W #= 71100000000.
```

Since the above will give me partially solved answer, I tried putting the keyword `label(Vars)` at the end. But this causes my execution of `grocery(V)` to produce

```
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.
```

While `grocery([V])` will give me a `false`. Can anyone enlighten me on how to do the labeling? Thanks

Edit : I did not put the call to the library clpfd earlier on

Comment: Please show what you actually entered. When I tried it, rather than an error, I just get no solutions.

Comment: That was what I actually entered. The one with an error is when I put label(Vars) and execute via grocery(V).

Comment: *How* you enter `label(Vars)` matters. You should enter, `grocery(Vars), label(Vars).` (note the comma after the first call). That's what I ran with your code and did not get an error, but did not get any solutions. If you enter `grocery(Vars).` with period, followed by `label(Vars).` then `label(Vars)` knows nothing about the `Vars` in the prior query. They're separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing two issues that I would like to discuss *separately*:

## Instantiation error

As you mentioned, we get:

```
?- grocery(Vs), label(Vs).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Labeling requires that the variables that are to be labeled all have *finite* domains. In your case, `label/1` throws an [instantiation-error](/questions/tagged/instantiation-error) because the domains of some variables are still **infinite**:

```
?- grocery([A,B,C,D]).
A in inf.. -1\/1..sup,
100*A#=_9006,
_9006 in inf.. -100\/100..sup,
_9006+_9084+_9078+_9072#=711,
_9006*_9084#=_9102,
_9084 in inf.. -100\/100..sup,
100*B#=_9084,
_9102 in inf.. -1\/1..sup,
_9102*_9078#=_9222,
_9078 in inf.. -100\/100..sup,
100*C#=_9078,
C in inf.. -1\/1..sup,
_9222 in -71100000000.. -1\/1..71100000000,
_9222*_9072#=71100000000,
_9072 in -71100000000.. -100\/100..71100000000,
100*D#=_9072,
D in -711000000.. -1\/1..711000000,
B in inf.. -1\/1..sup.
```

The only chance to correct this is to create a suitable **specialization** of the program, where the variables end up with finite domains. Writing `[Vs]` instead of `Vs` is obviously no solution:

```
?- grocery(Vs), label([Vs]).
ERROR: Type error: `integer' expected, found `[_8206,_9038,_8670,_8930]' (a list)
```

This is because `label/1` requires its argument to be a list of finite domain variables, *not* a list of *lists*.

An example of a *suitable* specialization could be:

```
?- grocery(Vs), Vs ins 0..sup, label(Vs).
false.
```

The resulting program has *no solution*, but at least we know that it *definitely* has no solution, because there is no more instantiation error.

## No solution

We have thus arrived at a second, rather *independent* question: *Why* does this resulting program have no solution?

A major advantage of using a logic programming language like Prolog is that it enables the application of **declarative debugging** approaches as for example shown in **GUPU**.

Like in GUPU, use the following definition to *generalize away* goals:

> ```
> :- op(950,fy, *).
>
> *_.
> ```

For example, we can *generalize away* the last goal of your program:

```
grocery(Vars):-
        Vars = [A,B,C,D],
        X #= 100 * A,
        Y #= 100 * B,
        Z #= 100 * C,
        W #= 100 * D,
        X+Y+Z+W #= 711,
        * X*Y*Z*W #= 71100000000.
```

The resulting program is obviously *more general* than the original program, because we have *removed a constraint* from a **pure** and **monotonic** Prolog program.

Now, we still get for the preceding query:

```
?- grocery(Vs), Vs ins 0..sup, label(Vs).
false.
```

And now we know: **Even the more general program has no solution.**

If you expect *solutions* in this case, you will have to *change portions of the remaining program* to correct the mistake in the formulation.

For more information about this approach, see [program-slicing](/questions/tagged/program-slicing) and [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity).